# angular fullstack generator grunt serve ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: angularjs, express, gruntjs

I'm building a project on a yeoman angular-fullstack generator. It's been a quite a while and the landing page was correctly loading after running  `grunt serve`  task.
I really don't know what I've done but now when I run `grunt serve`  I see ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED message in chrome first and then the landing page loads normally(about 5 seconds after  ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED message)

This makes my e2e tests crash.

found some issues on github about grunt-concurrent downgrading and disabling livereload but nothing helps..

This is the log. As you see express server has to start listening before open server and watch tasks( newly created fullstack-generator does that so it works correctly)

```
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task
>> 1 path cleaned.

Running "env:all" (env) task

Running "concurrent:pre" (concurrent) task

    Running "ngconstant:app" (ngconstant) task
    Creating module serviceboxApp.constants at client/app/app.constant.js...OK

    Done, without errors.


    Execution Time (2016-02-26 00:40:08 UTC)
    loading tasks              302ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 85%
    loading grunt-ng-constant   34ms  ▇▇▇▇ 10%
    ngconstant:app              19ms  ▇▇ 5%
    Total 356ms

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task

    Running "newer:babel:client" (newer) task

    Running "babel:client" (babel) task

    Running "newer-postrun:babel:client:1:/Users/apple/Desktop/dev/servicebox/node_modules/grunt-newer/.cache" (newer-postrun) task

    Done, without errors.


    Execution Time (2016-02-26 00:40:09 UTC)
    loading tasks        312ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 15%
    newer:babel:client    36ms  ▇ 2%
    loading grunt-babel  415ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 20%
    babel:client          1.2s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 61%
    Total 2s

Running "injector:scripts" (injector) task
Missing option `template`, using `dest` as template instead
Injecting js files (33 files)

Running "injector:css" (injector) task
Missing option `template`, using `dest` as template instead
Injecting css files (9 files)

Running "wiredep:client" (wiredep) task

Running "postcss:dist" (postcss) task

Running "express:dev" (express) task
Starting background Express server
Debugger listening on port 5858
[TypeError: Cannot read property 'Kerberos' of undefined]

Running "wait" task
>> Waiting for server reload...
Done waiting!

Running "open:server" (open) task

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
Express server listening on 9000, in development mode
finished populating users
finished populating quotes
finished populating poviders
```

Comment: it looks like this is your problem `[TypeError: Cannot read property 'Kerberos' of undefined]` can you post some more information detailing where you are calling Kerberos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have TypeError that is preventing your code from running properly. `[TypeError: Cannot read property 'Kerberos' of undefined]`

[You don't know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/ch1.md) explains that a TypeError "implies that Scope resolution was successful, but that there was an illegal/impossible action attempted against the result."

So you need to go back to where you are calling `Kerberos` and resolve the `TypeError`

Comment: my bad:( I solved it by installing kerberos, thank you